# A function $f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb R$ which is differentiable and uniformly continuous but $f'$ is unbounded on the interval.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, examples-counterexamples, solution-verification

I am finding an example of a function $f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb R$ which is differentiable and uniformly continuous but $f'$ is unbounded on the interval.
I constructed the function $f(x)=\frac{4x^3}{1+x^4} .\sin(\frac{1}{x^{10}})$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$ defined on the interval $(-1,1)$.I cannot find any flaw in my answer and I think it is a valid one.Can someone tell me if my answer is alright?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think you are misunderstanding the exercise. The example you gave has a derivative that blows up at $x=0$. Therefore, $f$ is not differentiable on $(-1,1)$.  How can you adjust your answer to make $x=1$ or $x=-1$ the blow up point?

Comment: A semicircle is enough, $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: @zugzug Notice that $f'(0)=0$ thus $f'$ is not continuous at $0$ but $f'(0)$ exists.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar You are absolutely right; I was being lazy, rather than use the definition of derivative at $0.$